# Send multiple files using ASP.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to send multiple files to ASP.net core webApi method.I have tried as shown below.But it always shows as `0 files`.Can you tell me why ?

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Consumes("application/json", "application/json-patch+json", "multipart/form-data")]
public class DocumentUploadController : CpcpControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<List<string>> AddDocument(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
    {
        foreach (var f in files)
        {
            var stream = f.OpenReadStream();
            var name = f.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

Postman :

[image]

But I can send 1 file as shown below.It's working fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> AddDocument(IFormFile file)
{
        var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
        var name = file.FileName;           
}
```

Comment: no difference. same result. that too shows as `0 files`. @Set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace key `file1` by `files` in postman. It works for me.

Comment: Yes,that is it.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hmm. I can only get this to work with param type of `IFormFile`. If I switch to `ICollection<IFormFile>` (or list or array), then I start getting "The input was not valid." back from the ASP.NET Core service.

Comment: @bugged87 i am facing the same issue as you ... did you solve it?

Comment: @User7291 see my posted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `IFormFileCollection` instead of `ICollection<IFormFile>` per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfilecollection?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Replace key file1 by files in postman.
Also we can also access files from Http Context as:

```
var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
```